# After using ListView Django cannot find my Template

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I writing catalog of shop-site, but i have a problem.

I used function ListView at views.py:
`class BagsListView (generic.ListView): model= Bag`

Also i have this code at urls.py:
`urlpatterns = [ ... re_path (r'^bags/$', views.BagsListView.as_view(), name='Bag'),]`

After runserver, when i go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/bags/ i got this false
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8wGP.png)

So, it was despite that i have every html files at every directory:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iScd0.png)

Can you please help me - where i got mistake?!

Thank you in advance..

To fix it i tried to specified template name
`class BagsListView (generic.ListView): model= Bag template_name = 'templates/bag_list.html'`
But it still doesnt work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `templates/` are root directories. Since your template is `catalog/bag_list.html`, your file tree should look like:

```
catalog/
    templates/
        catalog/
            bag_list.html
            …
    urls.py
    views.py
    …
```

so with a directory `catalog` in `templates` where the template files are placed under the second `catalog` directory. The view thus looks like:

```
class BagsListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Bag
    template_name = 'catalog/bag_list.html'
```

Comment: Thank you very much! 
I was at a dead end, you helped me a lot!